# Custom getter for properties from type parameters

Tags: kotlin

I have a Java file a little like so:

```
public class Thing {

    private String property;

    public Thing(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        if (property == null) {
            return "blah blah blah";
        } else {
            return property;
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously there's more to my actual class but the above is just an example.

I want to write this in Kotlin, so I started with this:

```
class Thing(val property: String?)
```

Then I tried to implement the custom getter using [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html) and [another Kotlin question](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/custom-getter-setter-for-properties-created-by-type-params/46/2) as reference, like this:

```
class Thing(property: String?) {

    val property: String? = property
        get() = property ?: "blah blah blah"

}
```

However, my IDE (Android Studio) highlights the second `property` on the 3rd line of the above code in red and gives me the message:

> Initializer is not allowed here because the property has no backing field

Why am I getting this error, and how would I be able to write this custom getter as described above?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use "field" instead of "property" in the body of your `get()` in order to declare a [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields):

```
class Thing(property: String?) {
    val property: String? = property
        get() = field ?: "blah blah blah"
}
```

However, in this particular example you might be better off with a non-null property declaration:

```
class Thing(property: String?) {
    val property: String = property ?: "blah blah blah"
}
```